# How to change transports: ['polling'], in android socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, websocket, socket.io

We are trying to establish the socket connection in android app.

we set transports ['polling']

and tried the bellow option but couldn't connect the socket

```
try {
            IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
            options.transports = new String[]{WebSocket.NAME};
            options.query = "token=my custom token";
           // Socket mSocket = IO.socket("https://example.com/", options);
            socket = IO.socket("https://example.com/socket.io/",options);

            socket.io().on(Manager.EVENT_TRANSPORT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Transport transport = (Transport)args[0];

                    transport.on(Transport.EVENT_REQUEST_HEADERS, new Emitter.Listener() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Object... args) {
                            headers.setProperty("x-clientid", AppApplication.getTokenKey());

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        socket.connect();
```

Comment: Thank you for `options.transports = new String[]{WebSocket.NAME};` (several transports here) and  `socket.io().on(Manager.EVENT_TRANSPORT, new Emitter.Listener()`!

Comment: See also https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues/625.